# Embedding Tkinter (and eventually others) source code inside a Python project

Tags: python, unix, tkinter

Maybe I just can't get the right search phrase on Google to find this, but I thought this may be useful to other users too.

I wrote a Python GUI for a program written in Fortran, but that's no the point (not the whole point).
My GUI is written using Tkinter interface, but I noticed not all Linux distros (actually I still haven't found on) come with python-tk installed.

How can I include python-tk source code in my program folder so that it can use it/install it when I run my program?

Talking about this, other two questions:
- would I be able to install 'gfortran' and 'gnuplot' (Unix programs), at least on apt-get systems, within a script? Or do I need root permissions anyway?
- could I include them in my source code too? In order to provide people a complete application which doesn't need any further installation to work.

Thank you in advance,

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Try to google [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It is able to pack libs and python itself for you.
If you want similar features under win. Try py2exe